# Does "as" in "an aggressive critic of what he saw as unfair Japanese trade practices in the 1980s." mean "because"?

Tags: meaning, as

I'm reading a book named *Chip War: The Fight for the World's Most Critical Technology*.

When I reading below paragraph：

> Jerry Sanders : Founder and CEO of AMD; Silicon Valley’s most
> flamboyant salesman; an aggressive critic of what he saw as unfair
> Japanese trade practices in the 1980s.

I want to accurate understand what meaning of "as" at here, so I look dictionary at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/as).

It seems that interpret "as" to "because" is better. Is it right?

Comment: If you scroll down on your “aggressive” page, you’ll see that the next definition is “determined”. That’s the one being used here. But you should maybe have raised it as a seperate question.

Comment: @BenMurphy Ok, I know, thank you.

Comment: This **as** is closely related to the **as** of this sentence: “Bob was not invited to the party, but he went as Alice's escort.”

Comment: @AntonSherwood Your comment give me a new problem, sorry, English is not my native language. Because I see party in "Bob was not invited to the party, but he went as Alice's escort.", so "escort" in  “Bob was not invited to the party, but he went as Alice's escort.” means "a person who goes with another person as a partner to a social event". It's not meaning "a person or vehicle that goes somewhere with someone to protect or guard them". Is it right?

Comment: @Tom Some people probably do take bodyguards to social events, so it could work either way, though I did have the ‘partner’ sense in mind.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I also believe that explaining it as "partner" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, the closest definition I can find in a reliable dictionary is this one from Oxford:

> *preposition*
> **1** used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has
> *it came as a shock*

With this function, it means Jerry Sanders *characterized* Japanese trade practices in the 1980s as unfair.

It does not mean "because". If we replace "as" with "because", the sentence makes no sense:

> *an aggressive critic of what he saw **because** unfair Japanese trade practices in the 1980s.

This grammar is impossible because the word "because" is a conjunction, but it joins two clauses together, not a clause ("he saw ____") and a noun phrase ("unfair Japanese trade practices in the 1980s").

Only a preposition fits there, and "because" is never a preposition.